# Cant loop through array of object in Vue#

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Cant loop trough array of object in Vue3

```
<template>
  <div
    class="shadow-xl w-96 h-96 md:h-[600px] md:w-[600px] lg:my-12 lg:w-[700px] lg:h-[700px] rounded-md"
  >
    <button @click="getData">Get data</button>
    <ul v-for="question in questions" :key="question.answer">
      <li>{{ question.answer }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the data looks like this:

```
questions: [
        { "answer": "Paris", "correct": true },
        { "answer": "Tokio", "correct": false },
        { "correct": false, "answer": "Dubai" },
        { "answer": "London", "correct": false }
      ]
```

they are in databse and i fetch them correcty; if i use

```
<ul v-for="question in questions" :key="question.answers">
      <li>{{ question.answers }}</li>
```

i get an array of an object that looks like this:

```
[ { "answer": "Paris", "correct": true }, { "answer": "Tokio", "correct": false }, { "answer": "Dubai", "correct": false }, { "answer": "London", "correct": false } ]
```

but if i want to show only cities name so i change the code to :

```
<ul v-for="question in questions" :key="question.answers">
      <li>{{ question.answer }}</li>
```

or even

```
   <ul v-for="question in questions" :key="question.answers">
      <li>{{ question.answers.answer }}</li>
```

but it doesnt work, where do i make a mistake?
i have 2 questions as a document in firestore. I thoght maybe i should you v-for two times...

```
<ul v-for="question in questions" :key="question.answers">
      <li>{{ question.answer }}</li>
```

or even

```
   <ul v-for="question in questions" :key="question.answers">
      <li>{{ question.answers.answer }}</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const questions = [
  [
        { "answer": "Paris", "correct": true },
        { "answer": "Tokio", "correct": false },
        { "correct": false, "answer": "Dubai" },
        { "answer": "London", "correct": false }
      ],
  [
        { "answer": "city 1", "correct": true },
        { "answer": "city 2", "correct": false },
        { "correct": false, "answer": "city 3" },
        { "answer": "city 4", "correct": false }
      ]
];
```

After the author provided the real API response the fix is easy, just use `Array::flat()`:

```
v-for="question in questions.flat()"
```

[LINK](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: thanks sir for answer, but i tried it and it didnt work :'(

Comment: @user21903805 check the gist, seems working

Comment: yes but i have two question in database, so it looks more like a https://shorturl.at/aKPY8

Comment: thats why i was wondering if i needed like two v-for loops

Comment: @user21903805 if you find the answer useful pls upvote (arrow up) and accept (checkbox)